# Why function not fired on click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I use tabs angular material in my project:
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples

Here is the code:

```
  <mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms" >
    <mat-tab></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab (click)="setData(upgrade.name)" [label]="upgrade.name" *ngFor="let upgrade of upgradeType; let i = index"> </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

the function:

```
  setData(data){
    alert(data)
  }
```

But when the tab is clicked the setData function is not executed.

Any idea why the setData function not executed when the tab is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

`mat-tab` doesn't have the click property.so, you need to use `mat-tab-group` property `(selectedTabChange)` to achieve. It will trigger once the tab changes.

**Try Using:**

**`mat-tab.component.html`**

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="setData($event)" animationDuration="0ms" >
    <mat-tab></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab [label]="upgrade.name" *ngFor="let upgrade of upgradeType; let i = index"> </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**`mat-tab.component.ts`**

```
setData(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    console.log("click", event.tab.textLabel); //console out will be click {{upgrade.name}}
}
```

Here's the working `stackblitz`:

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzc6m3-rpap1a?file=src/app/tab-group-align-example.html**

**Hope this helps :)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `selectedIndexChange`. Please check my code and link in the stackblitz given below =>
**HTML:**

```
<mat-tab-group 
               (selectedIndexChange)="test($event)">
 <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of upgradeType; let index = index" [label]="tab.name">
   <button mat-raised-button
            class="example-delete-tab-button"
            (click)="removeTab(index)">
      Delete Tab
    </button>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  upgradeType=[];
  constructor(){
    let temp=new UpgradeType();
    temp.name="A";
    temp.id=1;
    this.upgradeType.push(temp);
    let temp2=new UpgradeType();
    temp2.name="B";
    temp2.id=2;
    this.upgradeType.push(temp2);
  }
  test(index){
    console.log(index);
    console.log(this.upgradeType[index]);
  }
}
export class UpgradeType{
  name:string;
  id:number;
}
```

**NOTE:**  Code is available in stackblitz => [Demo code what you wanted](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selecting-mattab-zrhd7d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)